# How to Forward Values using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making one excel drawsheet for tennis.

[image: Excel drawsheet for tennis]

As you can see Federer has won 6-2 against opponent, so as I update score player whose value is max should be moved forward to where I have written formula goes here.

I also want the formula to check if the opponent value is Bye. Then the player should be moved to next round as in case 2 Nadal should be forwarded.

I am trying from past 3 days, but I am still not able to get the solution.

Please help.

Comment: I changed your tag from [excel-vba] to [excel-formula] as your title says you want to do this with a formula (and a formula **is** probably the right solution for this situation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate formula for D4 would be:

```
=IF(B3="Bye",B6,IF(B6="Bye",B3,IF(C4="","",IF(C4>C5,B3,B6))))
```

That will first check the two players' names for the word "Bye" and use the other player's name if appropriate.

Having determined it isn't a bye, it then checks to see whether the game is yet to be played and, if so, sets the winner's name to blank (as there isn't a winner until there is a score).

Once it is determined that the game has been played, it picks the name of whoever had the highest score.  (Note: It does not allow for a draw - I'm not sure whether the game you are scoring allows for "draws" or not.)

Comment: YowE3K : the above formula doesn't work it gives error

Comment: @AnkitaNanwani - there must have been some hidden special characters in there - it crashed for me too when I copy/pasted it into Excel but, once I retyped exactly the same thing, it worked.  I have retyped it into the answer, and have again copy/pasted it and it now works.

Comment: Now it working Fine but in not with the case 2 ie if the opponent player is Bye than Bye is moved forward here is the formula for case 2 as per the screenshot =IF(B7="Bye",B10,IF(B10="Bye",B10,IF(C8="","",IF(C8>C9,B7,B10))))

Comment: @AnkitaNanwani `IF(B10="Bye",B10,` - that is saying that, if B10 contains the value "Bye", set the result to B10 (i.e. "Bye") but I think you want the other player's name if one of the players' names is "Bye".

Comment: can you help with this too    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185496/how-to-pass-data-to-another-excel-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ankita just try this,, I've created 2 formula you can use either one,

=if(or(B51<>"Bye", B54<>"Bye"), if(C52>C53, B51, B54)

=IF (and(B51<>"Bye", C52>C53) B51,B54)

Here B51 & B54 carries Name C52 & C53 Score of B51 & B54.

Change cell addresses as you need.